# SQL Connect using PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, service-accounts

I'm unable to connect to SQL Server without passing password.

I have created a service account user in Active Directory and created a new login user for same in SQL Server, providing `db_creator` server role to it.

I then created a new database `Testdb` and provided `db_reader` & `db_writer` in user mapping. I need to run the PowerShell script from different computer for SQL authentication.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJTpn.jpg)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCspp.jpg)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTcz2.jpg)

I am using this connection string for SQL Server authentication:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIT9M.jpg)

I need to connect to SQL Server without passing password from different computers using that service account.

Comment: FWIW, that's not SQL Login authentication (which requires a username and password in the connection string), it's Windows Login authentication.

Comment: Is the PowerShell script getting executed in a PowerShell session using the MYLAB\TU1 credentials?